# Does iOS 7 support Applescript?

Tags: ios, ipad, applescript

While developing iOS 7 application on iPad can we use AppleScript?

Is it possible to use AppleScript while developing a iPad application?

Comment: No it's not supported.

Comment: @David,Then is there any other alternative??

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: No of course not. The whole idea of ios is to sandbox apps and give them very little outside access, and what little you get is tightly controlled. If you want to use an internal scripting language you can use JavaScript. There is a WWDC session on it 2013.

Comment: @Thomas, using Apple script i wanted to open other application particular window with filling some data inside that which is possible through apple script as it is there in mac application

Comment: You mean another application window in iOS or Mac OS X?

Comment: I meant in ios as it is already there in mac osx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, AppleScript isn't supported on iOS.

**edit**
If there is a specific third-party app you want to launch you can potentially open it using the app's custom URL scheme. If the app supports receiving data, then you can use their URL scheme to do so. [This website](http://handleopenurl.com/) has a list of supported third-party URL schemes. If this is your own app, then you can create your own scheme and handle it. [See here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) for more information on creating your own scheme.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas one doubt here i mean if app support recieving data what it means exactly. Firstly we need to send data from our app to another app. How it is possible without using applescript thats mine question. Launching other app will be fine. But how to fulfill data without applescript?

Comment: You need to use the URL format that the app supports. For example, the Twitter app supports URLs of the form `twitter://post?message=hello%20world&in_reply_to_status_id=12345
`. This lets you create a certain type of reply. You need to determine if the app you want to interact with supports a URL scheme and what types of commands it might support.

Comment: Ohk so you mean to say if i need to send data to other app then i nees to send the same in url format and from other app i need to extract the same data right??

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. When you send data you need to send the data in the format expected by the other application. If the other app can send data back to you then you need to support the format it sends.

Answer (score 1):

NO. 
AppleScript is supported only on macOS and not on iOS, WatchOS and tvOS. Applications are scriptable only on macOS and not on others. As already mentioned, custom URL schemes can be used to launch other apps.