# Calling/Executing applescript commands from a ios xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, applescript

So in my iOS Xcode project, I am trying to call an applescript code from Xcode. I know that this is possible for OS X but is it possible for iOS? For instance in OS X you can execute applescript code by using `NSAppleScript`. Is there an equivalent function in an iOS project?

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Applescript is not supported in iOS. If you want to open another application from your app then you can consider using URL scheme of the app (if it registers one).

More info can be found at : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW2

Comment: Okay so how would i open up applescript from xcode using the URL method. Would it be like this NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"applescript url] openURL:myURL];

Comment: You cannot run applescript from an iOS app. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286331/does-ios-7-support-applescript